# I cannot run the react native project in android studio emulator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
error ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml'. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:457:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:359:35)
    at getLaunchPackageName (E:\ReactJS\project1\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\getLaunchPackageName.js:161:33)
    at buildAndRun (E:\ReactJS\project1\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:163:63)
    at E:\ReactJS\project1\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:135:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (E:\ReactJS\project1\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:182:9)
```

Comment: How did you run the project ? Is it using react-native run-android ?

Answer (score 0):

add in your package.json :

```
"resolutions": {
"@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "2.9.0"
},
```